# How to remove the first character of an link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, substring, anchor

The goal I'm after is trimming the first character from each of the link's text.

```
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">1One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">2Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried simply substring and slice:

```
$('.item div a').substring(1);
$('.item div a').slice(1);
```

But after some fiddling, I've yet to get it to work. Then I attempted to use .text(), but it instead collects all the outputs from each link and replaces them, not individually. Which makes it so the end result is all the link text are the same.

```
var input = $('.item div a').text();
var output = input.substring(1);

$('.item div a').text(output);
```

Is there an alternative to using .substring() and .slice() to get this to work? (Also, I'm unable to alter the original HTML for this scenario)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.item div a')].forEach(a=>
a.innerHTML=a.innerHTML.substring(1))
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">1One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">2Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And jquery version:

```
$('.item div a').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1));
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you! I'll have to look into .forEach() now more closely.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(let i = 0;i<links.length;i++){
   var string = links[i].innerHTML;
   string=string.substring(1);
   console.log(string);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">1One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">2Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {

  $("a").each((idx,el) => el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.substring(1));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">1One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">2Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to iterate each instance.

The problem you had is jQuery `slice()` is for filtering the `$(selector)` collection and there is no jQuery `substring()` method

```js
$('.item a').text((i, curr) => curr.slice(1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">1One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <a href="">2Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```